# Wrapping Post Images in a Div

Tags: wordpress

This should not be a global function, but only relate to a given template, e.g. single.php:

I am looking for a way to wrap every image within a post in an additional div. I played with replace/filter functions, but couldn't figure it out.

(The idea is to place another div within that div, in order to place a sharing button comparable to http://news.distractify.com/culture/sandy-sanderson-cancars/ on each image.)

Answer (score 0):

I would use featured images. Activate featured images first. Designate a post to an image. then call that image in the loop using:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Then wrap that element inside the specified div for example:

```
<div id = "post-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
```

Actually I re-read your question. Take a look at this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery

You can add a gallery and each image in said gallery will have its own div class.

Comment: Thanks - but it should not be a gallery, but the continuous flow, see the example